# FFmpeg streaming to youtube very slowly

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, rtmp

Input:

```
const runCommand = require('./runCommand')

runCommand(
    'ffmpeg',
    `-threads:v 2 -threads:a 8 -filter_threads 2 -thread_queue_size 512 \
-loop 1 -i ./place.png \
-stream_loop -1 \
-i ./track.mp3 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -qp:v 19 -profile:v high -rc:v cbr_ld_hq -level:v 4.2 -r:v 60 -g:v 120 -bf:v 3 -refs:v 16 -preset fast -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/${process.env.streamkey}`,
    (data) => console.log(data),
    () => console.log('finished')
  )
```

Output:

```
x    
frame=  588 fps=8.7 q=21.0 size=    9000kB time=00:00:22.76 bitrate=3238.2kbits/s speed=0.339x    
frame=  590 fps=8.7 q=19.0 size=    9001kB time=00:00:22.83 bitrate=3229.4kbits/s speed=0.336x    
frame=  597 fps=8.7 q=21.0 size=    9007kB time=00:00:23.11 bitrate=3191.5kbits/s speed=0.337x    
frame=  603 fps=8.7 q=20.0 size=    9012kB time=00:00:23.36 bitrate=3159.3kbits/s speed=0.338x    
frame=  608 fps=8.7 q=21.0 size=    9016kB time=00:00:23.56 bitrate=3133.9kbits/s speed=0.339x    
frame=  614 fps=8.8 q=19.0 size=    9021kB time=00:00:23.80 bitrate=3104.9kbits/s speed=0.339x    
frame=  617 fps=8.7 q=21.0 size=   10702kB time=00:00:23.92 bitrate=3663.8kbits/s speed=0.337x    
frame=  623 fps=8.7 q=20.0 size=   10735kB time=00:00:24.16 bitrate=3638.9kbits/s speed=0.338x    
frame=  629 fps=8.7 q=21.0 size=   10740kB time=00:00:24.40 bitrate=3605.8kbits/s speed=0.338x    
frame=  635 fps=8.7 q=20.0 size=   10745kB time=00:00:24.63 bitrate=3573.1kbits/s speed=0.339x    
frame=  643 fps=8.8 q=20.0 size=   10751kB time=00:00:24.96 bitrate=3527.4kbits/s speed=0.341x    
frame=  646 fps=8.8 q=19.0 size=   10754kB time=00:00:25.08 bitrate=3512.1kbits/s speed=0.341x    
frame=  651 fps=8.8 q=20.0 size=   10758kB time=00:00:25.28 bitrate=3485.6kbits/s speed=0.341x    
frame=  656 fps=8.8 q=21.0 size=   10762kB time=00:00:25.48 bitrate=3459.6kbits/s speed=0.341x    
frame=  658 fps=8.7 q=19.0 size=   10764kB time=00:00:25.56 bitrate=3448.7kbits/s speed=0.338x    
frame=  664 fps=8.7 q=21.0 size=   10769kB time=00:00:25.81 bitrate=3417.9kbits/s speed=0.338x
```

Why is my FPS so low when streaming to Youtube?

P.S. The process is using very low memory and CPU, can I sacrifice a bit more for it?
[image]

Comment: Does the audio come through uninterrupted? If so, It's likely input bound. Reading your earlier posts (btw, you should delete them) looping on png file which is continuously overwritten by another process is less than ideal implementation, especially if file is written on a slow HDD. Consider using `-image2pipe` demuxer. See [this post](https://superuser.com/a/585800/1669011).

Comment: What happens when you run the `ffmpeg` command directly? Or use another source? Perhaps you have a network issue. And not per se a problem with ffmpeg.